# Groovy & Grails : how to get data from database through hasMany relation?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, grails, grails-orm

I've got two tables, Table1.groovy and Table2.groovy. Table1 has a hasMany relation to Table2, and Table2 belongsTo Table1. In MySQL workbench I can see, that this relation created a third table, which connects the above two tables through their ids - but these ids are generated, they are not in the corresponding .groovy file, and this third table not even have a .groovy file. I know the id from Table2, and I would need the id from Table1, what is connected to this Table2 id - question is, how can I access a table, what does not have a .groovy file, and only existing in the database? Looks like executeQuery can only access tables through their .groovy name. Is there any method  I could go "deeper", into the physically existing database? Or at least somehow get to know their ids?

Answer (score 0):

You can go from one domain to the other like this.

```
Table1.get(x).children
Table2.get(x).parent
```

Here *children* is the hasMany property and *parent* is the belongsTo.